# Apache Thrift: How to check on server side if the client is alive?

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

I have a thrift client written in Java and a Thrift server written in C++. Let's say the client invokes a time consuming function on the C++ server over thrift interface. IN this scenario, assume that the client dies before the server completes the execution of this time consuming function. Is there a handle or function in the thrift API to check in the server code whether the client is alive or not in order that the server can take some precaution before trying to send a response to the client that is already dead. Thanks.

Briefly, my question is can we determine in the server whether invoking client is alive? Is there a handle in the thrift API for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [TMonitoredServerSocket](http://twitter.github.com/commons/apidocs/com/twitter/common/thrift/monitoring/TMonitoredServerSocket.html)?

You can also look at [TServerEventHandler and TProcessorEventHandler](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1195) hooks.